# Changing the colour of specific list elements SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, list, swiftui

I have a list of 'players' in my app, and I want to some of them to have a different background colour depending on their properties.

Every Player object has a .active property that is either true or false. Depending on this value I want the background of that row to be a light grey rather than the white of the others. How would I do this? I was hoping it would be as simple as:

```
List(homeTeam.players) {player in
    HStack{
        Text("\(player.shirtNumber) - \(player.playerName)")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(player.timerText)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to achieve with `listRowBackground` modifier (but you need to use `ForEach` instead of `List` directly).

```
List {
   ForEach(homeTeam.players) {player in
      HStack{
        Text("\(player.shirtNumber) - \(player.playerName)")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(player.timerText)")
      }
      .listRowBackground(player.active ? Color(UIColor.lightGray) : 
         Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
   }
}
```