# SwiftUI List Item - Change color on click

Tags: macos, swiftui, xcode12

I have a list in a SwiftUI application on MacOS, i am trying to change the background color of the list item which is being clicked. I do not see a very clear solution to this yet, it was easier with the old UIKit Lists. Please if anyone have any clues to how to proceed?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64942577/12299030?

Comment: Thank you @Asperi but for me, i wish to change it on the click rather than from the beginning :(

Comment: you want when you click the background change and come back again to default or it keeps the color until you click again to remove the background color?

Comment: @Cod3rMax by default the color of the list item/background will be let us say gray and as soon as i click any item in the list - the item color must change to red or some other color and stay this way until i click some other item.

Comment: Would you show your own try code, so we could help with it, or you're just looking for copy-paste ready solution?